# How to show foreign key value in editmode (detailview)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a little problem with my gridview.
In Editmode I load a dropdownlist with content from my database (foreign key!).
When I save the changes and go after again in the editview, the dropdownlist shows the first entry from the table and not the value from the value that is saved. How can I set the default value in the dropdown to the value, that is set in the database, when I go in the editmode?

I hope my concern is understandable. Thank you very much for helping!

My Code (shorted)

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dtvProjektdetails" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlProjectDetails" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="ProjectID" DefaultMode="Edit" onitemupdating="dtvProjektdetails_ItemUpdating">
<Fields>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Segment" SortExpression="FK_Segment">
      <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSegment" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlDSSegment" DataTextField="Segment" DataValueField="SegID">
         </asp:DropDownList>
      </EditItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Datasource of the Dropdown (shorted)

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDSSegment" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CSLinker %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tabSegment] ORDER BY Segment]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Datasource of the Detailview:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlProjectDetails" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CSLinker %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tabProjects] WHERE ([ProjectID] = @ProjectID)" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tabProjects] SET [Name] = @Name, [ProejctNo] = @ProejctNo, [Startdate] = @Startdate, [Enddate] = @Enddate, [FK_Owner] = @FK_Owner, [FK_Segment] = @FK_Segment, [FK_ProjectCategorie] = @FK_ProjectCategorie, [FK_ProjectFiles] = @FK_ProjectFiles, [FK_Mailings] = @FK_Mailings, [Botschaft] = @Botschaft, [Ziel] = @Ziel, [Callmenge] = @Callmenge, [Quote] = @Quote, [Zielgruppe] = @Zielgruppe, [Inboundnummer] = @Inboundnummer, [Wissen] = @Wissen, [Prozess] = @Prozess, [Goodies] = @Goodies, [FK_Sprachen] = @FK_Sprachen WHERE [ProjectID] = @ProjectID">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblPID" Name="ProjectID" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int64" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ProejctNo" Type="String" />
            <%--<asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />--%>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Startdate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Enddate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="FK_Owner" Type="Int64" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="FK_Segment" Type="Int64" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="FK_ProjectCategorie" Type="Int64" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="FK_ProjectFiles" Type="Int64" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="FK_Mailings" Type="Int64" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Botschaft" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Ziel" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Callmenge" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Quote" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Zielgruppe" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Inboundnummer" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Wissen" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Prozess" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Goodies" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="FK_Sprachen" Type="Int64" />
            <%--<asp:Parameter Name="FK_Agenten" Type="Int64" />--%>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectID" Type="Int64" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the selectedvalue - property of the dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLinkCategorie" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlDScategorie"
                            DataTextField="Categorie" DataValueField="LinCatID" selectedvalue='<%Bind("columnName")%>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't works. "SelectedValue" isn't available.  There comes an error message ("The SelectedValue property can not be set declaratively.") :S

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSegment" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlDSSegment" DataTextField="Segment" SelectedValue='<%Bind("SegID")%>' DataValueField="SegID"></asp:DropDownList>

Comment: It is not a ASP- dropdownlist control property. Use the lowercase variant as I showed you in the example: 'selectedvalue' instead of 'SelectedValue'

Comment: ok, but that makes no difference. There comes the same error with "selectedvalue"

Comment: Check here: http://thepizzaboy.tumblr.com/post/449947554/selectedvalue-property-cannot-be-set-declaratively

Comment: that works know :). But now there come the following error: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'SegID'.
In my opinio it should work because SegID is contained in the Datasource "sqlDSSegment". Do you know a solution?

Comment: The SQL datasource automatically creates a set based on your select query. Verify that 'SELECT * FROM [tabProjects] WHERE ([ProjectID] = @ProjectID)' yields a column named 'SegID'. Check it by running the query in SQL Server (or PHPmyadmin if you use mysql)

Comment: Problem is solved. The problem was, that SegID was only in the seperate datasource of the dropdownlist but for <%Bind("SegID")%> it uses the datasource of the detailview. I use now the foreign key from the tabprojects (not tabSegment) and now it works -> SelectedValue='<%Bind("FK_SegID")%>'. Thank you very very much for the help!